# What happens on non iOS devices when Apple (map) URL Scheme is used?

Tags: android, ios, maps, url-scheme

For a physical address listed on a website, I wanted to make it clickable to open a map. I found the [Apple URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) page and have successfully set up a link like this http://maps.apple.com/?q=96+North+Main+St.,+Ashland+OR+97520 which works great on iOS and even Mavericks, launching the native Apple Maps app.

The question is, what happens on a non Apple device? (I don't have one to test). Would it just be a dead link for an Android user? Would the system somehow send it to Google maps instead? Or is there a more generic maps scheme I can use that'll just launch the user's preferred maps app/web service?

The platform I'm using (Squarespace) isn't set up to sniff the OS and deliver a different link based on it (or at least I'm not knowledgeable enough to make it happen!)

Thanks
-Joseph

Comment: Android 4.4 on Nexus 4 redirects to Google Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device that doesn't have Apple Maps will be redirected to the Google Maps website.